# Dynamics CRM 2015 Creating a button to start a workflow

Tags: crm, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

Hi I am currently trying to follow this guide:

https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/132235-create-a-workflow-short-cut-ribbon-button-no-code

So that I can create a button on the ribbon in CRM to start a workflow. The idea being that the user will fill in part of the form and then request approval.

However I have ran into an issue which is that at one point I have to define the library for the command actions to use and the guide state that we must use the "/_static/_common/scripts/RibbonActions.js" and the "/_static/_forms/form.js" library.

However not having done this before I have no idea how to include the library in the solution, so nothing appears on the library selection screen. I have tried searching how to complete this step but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood is that you are trying to call a workflow from javascript on click of a ribbon button. If you have any reference javascript assembly then both of them should be referred for the javascript method to work as expected.

Lets assume we have two different javascripts files like reference.js and actual.js And the button is supposed to call a method button_click from actual.js. In such a case we will be adding two commands as follows:

Library:reference.js and FunctionName:isNaN
Library:actual.js and FunctionName:button_click

This way the reference javascript also will be loaded and the method should be working properly. Hope I was able to address your query. Let me know if you have any questions or still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to enter plain text to library field instead of choosing from a selector.

Comment: Yes i noticed that however does the command action not have to refer to the java script file?